# Is there an API to get “Local events” from Google Maps?

Tags: google-maps

Is there an API to get "Local events" from [Google Maps](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Maps)?

The service is available only in a few cities: London, New York or Zurich. And you need to click on the Events option.

I'm trying to get such events as an RSS file, or to export an XML file.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking us to find an API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know the specific 'events' you are talking about, but your starting point should probably be [GData page](http://code.google.com/apis/gdata/docs/directory.html).

The data most probably be coming from Google Calendar or Google Base. Both of these already have API.